# how to make media queries work on Chrome's mobile phone simulator

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has mobile phone simulator in developer's tools[image].

But when I activate it and the viewport shrinks media queries don't detect it and the CSS rules specific to smartphones don't get applied. Is there any way I can make them detect the shrinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you select the desired size & sensors, did you tried to refresh the page?